# Is there any difference between original prints and PoD (Print on Demand) source books?

Tags: world-of-darkness, publishing

Regarding source books by Onyx Path/White Wolf (for the World of Darkness), is there any difference between original prints and PoD (Print on Demand) source books?

Basically, is there a way to know if a source book is an original print? Are there any differences in paper or print quality? Are there other ways to tell them apart?

Answer (score 8):

There are differences between books printed by White Wolf and those printed on demand by DriveThruRPG for Onyx Path or White Wolf, but they'll vary based upon the POD quality used to create the books (Standard or Premium). You'll find variations in paper quality and the richness of the black ink — a print-on-demand book will still look a lot like a high-quality laser printer, while the traditionally printed books will have stronger color presence. Also, if a hardback book has a sewn spine, rather than a glued one, that one's been traditionally printed.

Comment: This seems like an answer for the *general* difference between POD vs traditional prints. Do you have any feedback on WoD books and how to tell the difference that OP is asking?

Comment: @NautArch The things I write above are verifiably true about books produced by White Wolf (on its own or under license from CCP, when they were still making books for shelves) and those produced via POD from DriveThruRPG. Unfortunately, I haven't purchased a book from DTR that I also have an older version of on hand to contrast the two. Someone who does have such a set of books would be able to give a better, more complete answer, and I welcome them to do so.

Comment: there are *also* the kickstarter collectors editions...

Answer (score 3):

## No and a little yes.

There are basically three types of books that are published for the WoD that you can get on DTR:

- Re-created books. This is stuff from the old-old times, that was first officially published by DTR after the original prints were long years out of print. These PDFs and PoD books are 1:1 the original print.
- Simultanous Published. Most of the recent books (20th anniversary edition & 5th Edition) can be gotten a PoD or PDF. The POD shows a print date in the front. I know of no Errata that had been incorporated in the books like DTR does it for *The Dark Eye*.
- Collectors Editions. These don't differ in the print itself, but in the materials chosen. For example, Mage 20th Century was printed on heavier paper and had a silver side. These Collector books can't be re-ordered via POD and are usually somewhat easy to spot. They were only available by backing the Klickstarters.
- Also note that the backer preview PDFs at times do contain quite differences from the actual printed and final PDFs that ended in sale (and which the backers' also received). As an example: The Changeling 20th Anniversary Player's Guide swapped Inspire ** from "Make it Work" to "Toughen", a totally different power.